# how to get value property in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am parsing json using recusion .I call my function itself.I have two array in my json "array" and "list".I need to get property of "label" and save in array.I need to save values of label inside separate array of "list" and"label".I am trying to do that But I struck in my concept.i need to save in array if it property from "array"(json) I need to add in different array if property from "list".Property is label.

http://jsfiddle.net/mVz3E/

```
var arrayLabel=new Array();
var listLabel=new Array();
function recursiveIteration(object, callback) {
    for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof object[property] == "object"){
                recursiveIteration(object[property], callback);
            }else{
                //found a property which is not an object, check for your conditions here
                callback(object, property);

            }
        }
    }
}

function test_cb(object, property){
    if(property == "label" && object[property]&& object instanceof Array))
    {

        arrayLabel.push(object[property])

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to use your functions to retrieve the labels, but i did not understood how the listLabel array would look like.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jokuxe/2/edit) *updated*

```
 var json = {...};

 function test_cb(object, property, data) { 
   var array = [];
   if(data.filter(object, property) && object[property]){
     data.array.push(object[property]);
   }
 }

 recursiveIteration(json, test_cb, {
   array: arrayLabel, 
   filter: function(object, property){
          return (property == 'label' && !object.array);
        }
 });
 recursiveIteration(json, test_cb, {
 array: listLabel, 
   filter: function(object, property){
     console.dir(object);
     return (property == 'label' && !!object.list);
   }
 });

 console.log('arrayLabel',arrayLabel);
 console.log('listLabel',arrayLabel);
 document.body.textContent = 'arrayLabel: ' + arrayLabel.join(', ') + 
                      ' - listLabel: ' + listLabel.join(', ');
```

Comment: the expected awswer is arrayLabel :33, 44.and  listLabel is 11,23

Comment: now I got u ... plz read more about [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) ... i did i found it quite amusing!